# Insert to an identity column using sequences in DB2

Tags: db2, identity, sql-insert

How do I insert to an identity column using sequences in DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (seq, val1, val2, ...) VALUES (NEXTVAL FROM seq, val1, val2, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (seq, val1, val2, ...) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR seq, val1, val2, ...)
```